# Identity of unnamed enums with no enumerators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider a program with the following two translation units:

```
// TU 1
#include <typeinfo>
struct S {
    enum { } x;
};
const std::type_info& ti1 = typeid(decltype(S::x));


// TU 2
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
struct S {
    enum { } x;
};
extern std::type_info& ti1;
const std::type_info& ti2 = typeid(decltype(S::x));
int main() {
    std::cout << (ti1 == ti2) << '\n';
}
```

I compiled it with GCC and Clang and in both cases the result was 1, and I'm not sure why. (GCC also warns that "ISO C++ forbids empty unnamed enum", which I don't think is true.)

[[dcl.enum]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#11) states that if an unnamed enumeration does not have a typedef name for linkage purposes but has at least one enumerator, then it has its first enumerator as its name for linkage purposes. These enums have no enumerators, so they have no name for linkage purposes. The same paragraph also has the following note which seems to be a natural consequence of not giving the enums names for linkage purposes:

> [Note 3: Each unnamed enumeration with no enumerators is a distinct type. — end note]

Perhaps both compilers have a bug. Or, more likely, I just misunderstood the note. The note is non-normative anyway, so let's look at some normative wording.

[[basic.link]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8)

> Two declarations of entities declare the same entity if, considering declarations of unnamed types to introduce their names for linkage purposes, if any ([dcl.typedef], [dcl.enum]), they correspond ([basic.scope.scope]), have the same target scope that is not a function or template parameter scope, and
>
> - [irrelevant]
> - [irrelevant]
> - they both declare names with external linkage.

[[basic.scope.scope]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#4)

> Two declarations correspond if they (re)introduce the same name, both declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless [irrelevant]

It seems that, when an unnamed enum is not given a typedef name for linkage purposes, and has no enumerators, it can't be the same type as itself in a different translation unit.

So is it really just a compiler bug? One last thing I was thinking is that if the two enum types really are distinct, then the multiple definitions of `S` violate the one-definition rule and make the program ill-formed NDR. But I couldn't find anything in the ODR that actually says that.

Comment: Interestingly, having `enum {} x;` at global scope in one TU and `enum {} y;` in the other TU gives the same typeid in Clang, but different ones in GCC.

Comment: If they are distinct types doesn't `S` violate ODR?

Comment: _they both declare names with external linkage_ in [basic.link]/8 is also irrelevant

Comment: ... and if `S` violates ODR, you have an ill-formed ndr program.  So all compilers are correct.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont If you can find the specific paragraph that makes it an ODR violation, please post an answer. Personally, I would find it surprising if the standard intended to disallow this. If such counterintuitive behaviour were really intended, I would expect at least a compiler warning.

Comment: @brian defining the same named type in two compilation units as not being the same is pretty classic ODR violation?  If the standard does not make your code illegal, it is a defect in the standard.  ODR violations are almost always ill-formed NDR.    It is inconcievable to me that your two types S would ever be intended to be legal as written.  Itbis exactly what ODR is about banning?  Or maybe I misread your code.  And no, ODR violations don't reliably generate warnings.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think it would be extremely counterintuitive to say that `struct S { enum { E } x; };` is allowed to be multiply defined, but `struct S { enum { } x; };` is not! If this were truly the case, then compilers should warn in *every* translation unit whenever there's such a definition with external linkage, because the probability of causing an ODR violation is high.

Comment: @brian Either `enum{}x` is the same type (in which case the typeids should match) or it doesn't (in which case odr violation should occur).  So typeid of `&S::x` can.be the same regardless.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont If you're confident that the answer is "it *should* be an ODR violation, but the standard doesn't say so and I consider this a defect", then please post that as an answer.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying why empty enums are so interesting (beyond a language lawyering scope)? Is this about automated code generation or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This program is well-formed and prints 1, as seen.  Because `S` is defined identically in both translation units with external linkage, it is as if there is **one** definition of `S` ([basic.def.odr]/14) and thus only one enumeration type is defined.  (In practice it is mangled based on the name `S` or `S::x`.)

This is just the same phenomenon as static local variables and lambdas being shared among the definitions of an **inline** function:

```
// foo.hh
inline int* f() {static int x; return &x;}
inline auto g(int *p) {return [p] {return p;};}
inline std::vector<decltype(g(nullptr))> v;
```

```
// bar.cc
#include"foo.hh"
void init() {v.push_back(g(f()));}
```

```
// main.cc
#include"foo.hh"
void init();
int main() {
  init();
  return v.front()()!=f();  // 0
}
```